# Hummingbird (Now Flutter for web) is planned for release. Should I stop learning AngularDart?

Tags: flutter, angular-dart

With the recent [announcement](https://medium.com/flutter-io/hummingbird-building-flutter-for-the-web-e687c2a023a8) of Hummingbird, it looks like Flutter will mature for web apps. I was trying to learn AngularDart, but I personally believe Flutter web apps will be a better approach. I'd have to plan a lot to share my codebase between Flutter and AngularDart.

Will Hummingbird receive support for Flutter web apps? Does the use of AngularDart will have diminishing returns in the future?

I understand the answers might be very subjective, but maybe it would be better to discuss some serious advantages and disadvantages of `flutter-web`.

**Update (13.09.2019)** Hummningbird is now Flutter-Web and Flutter-Web is now merged to Flutter branch. Things have changed for good ;)

Answer (score 3):

As always, the answer is: It depends.

If you want to reach a lot of users quickly, AngularDart is your friend as it provides a solid foundation right now.
Also notice that doing a lot of "planning to share your codebase", which basically translates to thinking about separating your business logic from your UI logic, is a win either way because the more modular code will benefit you in the long run.
Additionally, it's never a bad thing to get to know more frameworks.

However, if you can allow yourself to be patient and you're thinking in the long term, Flutter's future support for web and Fuchsia may intrigue you.
That's why - if you believe in Flutter's success - it can make sense to only develop for Flutter and then wait and see what's about to happen.

Personally, I believe Flutter will become a well-supported, versatile, general UI framework.
That's why I would recommend betting on Flutter if your project is not time-critical.

Answer (score 2):

I think it really depends on your use case. AngularDart and angular_components are trying to support a more 'enterprise' use case. Complex web apps that are primarily desktop focused. While HummingBird is focusing more on the mobile web use case or where you already have a flutter app that you happen to want to target web also with the same target. So both will have a place.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you very wel ;-)
I'm now tryin to recycle my carrer and been a lot of months learning Angular (The Typescript branch) I love work with it, so pleasant an so intuitive, I did some major web apps than are working very well ant the mantainence is easy, quick and clean ... the future seemed me and Angula in a long love afaire ...

But sudenly I hear about Flutter, like two monts ago, and I was captivated for the concept (before I already had try different aproachs to have one codebase an reach all mobile platforms, Xamarin in major part, and was painfull to learn and to use, ReactNative never make me feel anything), but Flutter is soo easy, with so much power than Xcode and Swift witch I been workin too and with wich when you have a middle project the storyboard is intelligible. I been learning Flutter full time last two months, already have app in appstores and doing my first web (wonderfull experince doing web without css, ohhhh yes).

Then my opinion is similart to the others "depends", but if I was you and was just starting to learn AngularDart I will go for Flutter without loocking back.